# Group Queryset by numbers in Template

Tags: django

I've got a problem where I've to display all objects from a model in a view. However, I've got space to show only 3 at a time. So i was thinking of using a sliding frame (Bootstrap Carousel) to display more than 3.

I have come to 2 solutions.

1: I create a view that is called via ajax that loads the subsequent objects using a `start_id` that displays 3 objects from the model starting with the primary key of the object as `start_id`. 
Something along these lines.

```
    def dynamic_banners(request):
        start = request.GET['start_id']
        banner1 = Sample.objects.filter(id__exact=start)
        banner2 = Sample.objects.filter(id__exact=start+1)
        banner3 = Sample.objects.filter(id__exact=start+2)

        return render_to_response('template.html',{'banner1':banner1, 'banner2':banner2, 'banner3':banner3}, RequestContext(request))
```

But I'm not sure if this is an elegant or, for that matter, a correct solution.

2: Another solution is sending all Objects to the view at once and then splitting them up in the template. The problem here is, I can't work out a way to do this.

I hope the problem seems coherent. 
Otherwise you can always have a look at the app [here](http://silverinnings.herokuapp.com) and look at the 'Featured Service Providers' where I can currently display only 3 but need to display all in a manner of a sliding frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dynamic_banners(request):
    start = request.GET['start_id']
    banners = Sample.objects.filter(id__gte=start).order_by('id')[:3]
    return render_to_response('template.html',{'banners':banners}, RequestContext(request))
```